# urban airship push notification problem in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I use the urban airship mail push notification service , i created some sample application and register the package name in urban airmail ship , then i got the application key , 
but in raw/ua.properties , i need to specify the

```
debug.app_key=
production.app_key=
```

but i don`t know the value , from where i have to get the value for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link for implementing [Push Notification](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/p/push-notification-in-android-using.html).

After you create your Application you will get the Application Key put that Key in the place of debug.app.key then in case of production.app.key generate the MD5 fingerprint by using

```
keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

after getting the fingerprint put in the pruoduction.app.key..

Comment: i did as you say , but it will show following error                    04-25 17:11:56.885: INFO/AirMail(294): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Transport endpoint is not connected  04-25 17:14:27.225: INFO/AirMail(294):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)

Comment: You want to send Notification in Message or Notification in RSS Feed?

Comment: Notification in message i need to send

Comment: +1 venky your answer gave me idea about "productionAppKey" in "airshipconfig.properties" file

Comment: Are you sure about productionAppKey? Isn't it the app key availble in the UA web app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936694/development-app-key-and-app-secret-for-android