# Development App Key and App Secret for Android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to set up a push notification for android app using urban airship with Helium option. However, I need to find these information for my app which I have no idea where to find from. any comments or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
For setting up Helium, make sure your transport is set correctly. Valid answers for transport are: helium or c2dm. The following should go in the assets/airshipconfig.properties of your project.

transport = helium
developmentAppKey = Your Development App Key
developmentAppSecret = Your Development App Secret
productionAppKey = Your Production App Key
productionAppSecret = Your Production App Secret
inProduction = false
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These keys are found on the UrbanAirship website once you have set up an application.

Once this is done you can click 'Visit application' and you will be able to see the keys, which you then put in the app.

They basically tell the Android app you are developing which application on the Urban Airship service to connect to.

[image]

Comment: ah ok.. thank you so much for your answer to this. they instruction is not better than yours.

Comment: You can see this info here: "Your app -> Settings -> APIs & Integrations".